# Why there is a black gap between UICollectionView cells?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to display several cells in a UICollectionView in this manner: each cell is like a page to user, and an active UICollectionViewCell should occupy the full bound of the UICollectionView.

[image]

However for some reasons, there is black gap between cells after scrolling right.

[image]

Why does it happen?

I have already defined this function to control the size of "page" view:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     
    // the size is half of the screen
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/2.0);
}
```

Comment: Have you set the `sectionInset` and `minSpacing` to 0. You need to set them on the layout object you are using.

Comment: Looks like minSpacing alone fixed my problem. Please put your comment in an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to set minSpacing to 0.

This sets the minimum gap between each item and also between the items and the edge of the collection view.